# How to retrieve all the facts resulting of an inference of chain rules in Prolog

Tags: prolog, ffi, swi-prolog, jpl

I have implemented several chain rules in a way that the last rule obtain the desired result depending on the result of the previous ones.

```
rule1(X,Y) :-
   pred1(X,Z),
   pred1(Y,Z).

rule2(Z,T) :- 
   rule1(X,Y),
   pred2(Z,X),
   pred2(T,Y).
```

I need to obtain every fact that has been inferred for each one of the rules. I'm doing this from Java using the jpl library.

```
String stringFileQuery = "rule1(X,Y)";
System.out.println(stringFileQuery + " "
   + (Query.hasSolution(stringFileQuery) ? "succeeded" : "failed"));
Query fileQuery = new Query(stringFileQuery);
System.out.println("all solutions of " + stringFileQuery);
while (fileQuery.hasMoreSolutions()) {
    Map<String, Term> s10 = fileQuery.nextSolution();
    System.out.println("First -> " + s10.get("X") + ", Second ->" + 10.get("Y"));
}
```

How can I obtain all these facts, even in Prolog? In the real program, I have more that two rules.

Comment: Did you mean `rule1(X,Y) :- pred1(X,Z), pred1(Y,Z).` and `rule2(Z,T) :- rule1(X,Y), pred2(Z,X), pred2(T,Y).`?

Comment: Yes, the idea is that the top rule is built on top of the other by connecting its predicates; and for every call of the rule2 I need to obtain the obtained facts.

Comment: So if you check for `rule1(X,Y)`, you'd like to see `pred1(X,Z), pred1(Y,Z)` and if you check for `rule2(Z,T)`, you'd like to see `pred1(X,Z), pred1(Y,Z), pred2(Z,X), pred2(T,Y)`?

Comment: But I needed to know whether is possible to check the top rule, e.g. rule1, and retrieve all the results of the inference process for the other rules, like backtracking all the process.

Comment: Could you please update your question with examples of what you're looking for? Like "I put in `pred1(X, Y)`, so I expect the output ...; I put in `pred2(Z,T)`, so I expect the output ..."?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for here, is a [meta-interpreter](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/prolog_misc/acomip.html) for Prolog that records the facts as it goes along. Since Prolog is a [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) language, writing a simple meta-interpreter is [trivial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#Meta-interpreters_and_reflection).

You probably will want to use `clause_property/2` to check if a clause you're examining is a fact, like so

```
recordFacts(Goal, [Goal|Facts]) :-
    clause(Goal, _Body, Ref),
    clause_property(Ref, fact).
```

---

#### Edit

A complete example would be something like

```
recordFacts(Goal, Facts) :-
    recordFacts(Goal, [], AllFacts),
    list_to_set(AllFacts, Facts).

recordFacts((Goal, RestOfGoals), FactsIn, FactsOut) :-
    recordFacts(Goal, FactsIn, FactsH),
    recordFacts(RestOfGoals, FactsH, FactsOut).

recordFacts(Goal, Facts, [Goal|Facts]) :-
    clause(Goal, _, Ref),
    clause_property(Ref, fact).

recordFacts(Goal, FactsIn, FactsOut) :-
    clause(Goal, Body, Ref),
    not(clause_property(Ref, fact)),
    not(clause_property(Ref, predicate(system: (',')/2))),
    recordFacts(Body, FactsIn, FactsOut).
```